# How to make a function execute at the desired periods using c++ 11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I want to using c++ 11 to implement a function like the windows API [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx),like that"do something every 2 second"

Comment: Well you usually use a timer for that. Or a while loop which will `sleep(2000)` for 2 seconds after calling your function.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposed you want to have this function being executed every 2 seconds

```
void foo() {
    cout << "Hello from foo()!" << endl;
}
```

You can provide a simple `timed_execution` class using various c++11 mechanisms

```
struct timed_execution {
    typedef void (*func_type)(void);
    timed_execution(func_type func, const std::chrono::milliseconds period) 
        : func_(func)
        , period_(period)
        , thread_(std::bind(&timed_execution::threadFunc,this))
    {
    }
private:        
    void threadFunc() {
        while(true) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(period_);
            func_();
        }
    }
    func_type func_;
    const std::chrono::milliseconds period_;
    std::thread thread_;
};
```

To run the function asynchronously with a certain period, you'll simply create an instance of this class:

```
int main() {
    timed_execution t(foo,std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
    return 0;
}
```

See a [live sample here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4429a06744a86178) please.

---

Making use of templates/variadic templates to provide the actually to be executed function's parameters and return types on top, seems to be a good idea to improve the `timed_execution` class and go for a `timer` class as folows:

```
template<typename CALLBACK_T>
struct timer {

    template<typename D>
    timer(CALLBACK_T func, const D& period) 
        : func_(func)
        , period_(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( period ))
        , thread_(std::bind(&timer::threadFunc,this))
    {
    }
private:        
    void threadFunc() {
        while(true) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(period_);
            func_();
        }
    }
    CALLBACK_T func_;
    const std::chrono::milliseconds period_;
    std::thread thread_;
};
```

---

And have a separate `make_timer()` function to instantiate it

```
template<typename CALLBACK_T , typename D>
timer<typename std::decay<CALLBACK_T>::type> make_timer( CALLBACK_T&& callback , D&& duration )
{
    return { std::forward<CALLBACK_T>( callback ) , std::forward<D>( duration ) };   
}
```

---

```
int main() {
    auto timer = make_timer(foo,std::chrono::seconds(1));
    auto other = make_timer( [](){ std::cout << "Hello from lambda!\n"; } , std::chrono::seconds{ 1 } );

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Since this is pure C++11, let me note something: Could be only my subjective opinion, but I always think that C++11 `using` type aliases look much better than the good old `typedef`, specially for function pointers. Compare `void(*FuncType)()` vs `using FuncType = void()`

Comment: @Manu343726 You mean `using void (*func_type)(void);` instead of `typedef void (*func_type)(void);`?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Also I was thinking this could be improved with a `make_timer()` function for type inference. Imagine something like `auto timer = make_timer([](){ std::cout << "Hello!\n"; } , std::chrono::seconds{ 30 } );` Cool, isn't?

Comment: @Manu343726 I'd appreciate more helpful improvements by the direction I tried to point out to, with the 2nd part of my answer. Feel free to edit or add better samples.

Comment: I was thinking about parameters ans return values. Since this is a timer there is no easy way to get return values from the callback (Is not a coroutine, isn't? :P ), and also passing parameters to the callback is not easy (What parameters? When and how?). I think the best way is to use `std::bind()` to bind some parameters to the callback, but the signature of the final callback passed to the timer should be without parameters.

Comment: @Manu343726 I like your idea, to have that separate function constructing such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

```
template< class Rep, class Period >
void sleep_for( const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& sleep_duration );
```

as in the following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void other_thread() {
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 2000 );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
    std::cout << "Waited 2000 ms\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(other_thread);
    std::cout << "Waiting 2 seconds in a secondary thread.." << std::endl;
    t.join();
    std::cout << "Thread has completed its job" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example (don't forget -pthread)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a4356783624f7b9)

Comment: I think from the question you should point out how to do this asynchronously in a separate thread's function rather than in `main()`.

Comment: That's a partially incomplete answer, there is no strong requirements on waking up the thread after 2000ms precisely, and not even in a small acceptable delta. Only a real time OS have that kind of mechanism, windows, macos or linux are not…

Comment: @galop1n OP asked for something like [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) which is a Windows timer routine for windows message dispatch. I seriously doubt someone could understand the question with a real time bias (I agree on Windows, MacOS systems, not on linux **iff** you install a kernel patch: [Xenomai](http://www.xenomai.org/))